# Border colours of canvases (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I need help with changing the border colour of a canvas in tkinter

This is my code:

```
w = int(root.winfo_screenwidth())
loader = Canvas(width=w, height=20, bd=1)
loader.grid(column=0, row=1)
```

I have tried:

```
fill="black"
outline="black"
bd="black"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `highlightbackground` option to change color of <s>border</s> highlight ring(which is also a border-like thing, but is separate from the actual border). (correction, thanks to [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250235/border-colours-of-canvases-tkinter/42250568#comment71661379_42250568) )

To change <s>border</s> highlight ring thickness, you should use `highlightthickness` option.

```
loader = Canvas(..., highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="black")
```

Also, if you want to remove that <s>border</s> highlight ring , you can set `highlightthickness` to `0`.

```
loader = Canvas(..., highlightthickness=0)
```

Comment: Careful with terminology: highlightbackground doesn't change the color of the border per se, it changes the color of the highlight ring (which is also a border-like thing, but is separate from the actual border).

Comment: @BryanOakley Ah, sorry. Fixing it. As always, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

**tkinter Canvas allows TWO borders** ( **Python 3.9** `tkinter.TkVersion` **8.6** )

A 'normal' border and a highlight border. To change their color and thickness properties set the `bd`, `bg`, `highlightthickness` and `highlightbackground` named parameter:

```
obj_tkinter_Canvas = tkinter.Canvas( ..., 
    bd = 2
    bg = 'white'
    highlightthickness  = 1, 
    highlightbackground = 'white'
)
```

The integers are border thicknesses in pixels. The background colors are set using symbolic names ( see  for example https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/colors.html for a list of available color names ).